# If $a_n>0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nx^n=A$ then $\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n=A$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers and $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nx^n=A$. Prove that $\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n=A$.

By Abel's theorem, if $\sum a_n$ converges then it must coverge to $A$. So I tried to show that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above but failed. I also tried the inequality
$$ |A-\sum^N_{n=0}a_n|\leq|A-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n|+|\sum^\infty_{N+1}a_nx^n|+|\sum^N_{n=0}a_n(x^n-1)|\mbox{.}$$
Since $\sum a_nx^n$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$, this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $N$ we have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}a_n=\lim_{x\to 1-} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_nx^{n} \leq \lim \inf_{x\to 1-} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n}=A$. Let $N \to \infty$. On the other hand $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n}\leq \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ for all $x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $0 < x < 1$ and $N \in \Bbb N$ is
$$
 x^N \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \le \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \, .
$$
For $x \to 1^-$ it follows that
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \le A \, .
$$
So the partial sums of $\sum a_n$ are bounded above, which implies that the series is convergent.